# How to use a raw query in Django that uses an external database as well as a Django model

Tags: python, sql, django

I have an external database with source data. (Microsoft db)
How can I query this database and do an inner join on a Django model?
I have two connections set up in settings.py
This way I can acces the external database like this:

```
with connection['externalDB'].cursor() as c:
```

This external db has millions of records. I want run a query and then save that model into another Django model.

```
SELECT 
    x.product -> External db
    ,d.client_name -> Django model
FROM 
    [external db] x
INNER JOIN 
    [django model] d ON x.client_id = d.client_id
WHERE 
    d.client_name = 'foo.
```

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get results from one database and apply this output as a filter for another query on second database
You can check [Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to insert it into the Django database, not filter it.

Comment: Also in insert operation, you can get data and use create() or bulk_create()

Comment: The way I do it now is to get the data and store it in an pandas df, then use bulk_create to save it. But can you give me an example how I would do it skipped the pandas part? Or do I have to store the data first somewhere?